# Apply a custom function to each column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let say I have below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
Dat = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2], 'b' : [3,4]})

def MyFunc(x, y) :
  return x + y ** (.5)
```

Now I want to apply above custom function to elements of each of the columns of `Dat`.

Is there any function/method to achieve this?

I have gone through different suggestions over internet, however all of them talk mainly application of standard python function e.g. `sum()`

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a function, you can use directly:

```
Dat.iloc[0]+Dat.iloc[1]**.5
```

If really you need the function:

```
MyFunc(Dat.iloc[0], Dat.iloc[1])
```

Or:

```
tmp = Dat.T

MyFunc(tmp[0], tmp[1])
```

Output:

```
a    2.414214
b    5.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass rows by select by labels by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print(MyFunc(Dat.loc[0], Dat.loc[1]))
a    2.414214
b    5.000000
dtype: float64

print(MyFunc(Dat.iloc[0], Dat.iloc[1]))
a    2.414214
b    5.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am expecting this calculation `1 + 2 ** (.5); 3 + 4 ** (.5)`

Comment: @BrianSmith - So there are always 2 rows?

Comment: yes, that is the reason `MyFunc ` has 2 arguments. But number of columns may be any

Comment: @BrianSmith - Solution was updated.